# How can I get storm topology status via java code?

Tags: status, apache-storm, topology

I'm very new at storm. I want to manage two topology which they need to inform about their status. Is it impossible that I understand status of topology is deactivated or not to submit another one in java class?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Thrift API:

```
  NimbusClient nimbusClient = NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(Utils.readDefaultConfig())
  nimbusClient.getClient().getClusterInfo().get_topologies()
  …
```

See https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/blob/master/storm-core/src/storm.thrift

Comment: Thanks, but since it uses NimbusClient, can I test it in local system without any cluster?

Comment: @saharshokouhi Try it first!